# After deploying the code to server the style sheets are working differently

Tags: asp.net, css

I developed an app locally which is working great in IE, Firefox, Chrome. I deployed it to the server and funny that it doesn't look the same any more.It is smaller / no space between cells...etc

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some actual code and/or screen shots or a live example. Can you set up a live example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the individual elements to see what styles are being applied. Google Chrome has this functionality built in. Compare the results on the live server to what you're seeing in development. You'll likely discover that a style sheet is not being loaded in one environment vs. the other.

Comment: I tried using firbug. It didn't helped. I don't see some styles at all when I use firefox. Something is fishy.

Comment: #content fieldset {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 980px;

Comment: I am seeing above CSS in the app that is working and in the other App I am not even seeing Fieldset.

Comment: If you don't see some of the styles, consider the possibility that the corresponding style sheet isn't where you expect it to be. Try to fetch the style sheet using your browser itself. (e.g., http://www.mysite.com/styles/mystylesheet.css)

Comment: When I called it from mysite.com/styles/mystlesheet.css it is not displying css because of permissions I changed the permissions and it is working. Thank you,